# Merge two projects

Tags: codenameone

I have two individual projects in codename one both are running fine, now I want to merge these two projects into one. I know how I can combine code and class files but I want know how I can combine `theme.res` file of two projects as there are at least 15-17 form in one `theme.res` file and it's difficult to create all again. Please suggest if there is any way I can combine two `theme.res` files or I can use two `theme.res` files in one project.
e.g.

Project 1: name: test1 having theme.res file with 12 Form

Project 2: name: test2 having theme.res file with 18 Form

New project: name:Merge= test1+test2 (if possible one theme.res file with 12+18 = 30 form)

Answer (score 0):

The designer has an import feature that allows importing a res file into another. I suggest copying both files to a backup before starting, then removing duplicates from the file you are about to import (e.g. theme etc.) then importing into the other file.

Comment: Hi Almog,Thanks for reply. 
I did changes as you suggested it's working fine with simulator but not working on device.
On Device its giving me internal application error at time of start only. 
Under log showing "nullpointerexception" when LoginForm call from main page.
Error at Line:
LoginForm.java:58 "mLoginForm = (Form) createContainer(Constants.APP_THEME, "LoginScreen");" and public static final String APP_THEME = "/theme";
MyApplication.java:83 "LoginForm.getLoginForm().ShowLoginForm();

Comment: Its not really practical to describe this issue over stack overflow. Its hard for me to understand. Some forms might be renamed during the import so you might need to adapt some of the code.